# python cronjob not deleted after remove_all

Tags: python, cron

TLDR: Using python, crontab.remove_all appears to be working, but when I instanciate a new crontab, I can see that the remove_all command didn't work.

Long question :
I'm trying to use cronjobs in my project, but before that I want to be able to test them. As I don't want to have an infinity of jobs running, I need to first be able to delete them. However, it doesn't work as I thought it would.

Here is my code :

```py
    def test_understanding_cronjobs(self):
        """
        Just trying to understand cronjobs and how to delete them.
        The main point of this experiment is to have a way to clean everything
        between each test.
        """
        # First we instanciate a crontab object.
        crontab = CronTab(user="root")

        # Then we make sure that there are no other test cronjobs running.
        # I know everything should be clean at the start of a test, but this is to show
        # that my environment is clean.
        crontab.remove_all(comment="test")
        # There should be no job at all now.
        self.assertEqual(len(crontab), 0)

        # We create a single job, with a comment that will allow us to kown that it's a test.
        # https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/
        job = crontab.new(command="ls -al /tmp", comment="test")
        job.minute.every(1)
        crontab.write()

        # At this point we should have one and only one job.
        self.assertEqual(len(crontab), 1)

        # Let's delete all test jobs.
        crontab.remove_all(comment="test")
        # There should be no job at all now.
        self.assertEqual(len(crontab), 0)

        # Just to be sure, let's create a new crontab instance and verify this information.
        clean_crontab = CronTab(user="root")
        self.assertEqual(len(clean_crontab), 0)
        # But here I get : AssertionError: 1 != 0, self.assertEqual(len(clean_crontab), 0)
```

If you have any ideas as to what's happening there, I would really like to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crontab` just interacts with the system's cron management. If you don't `write` the changes, they're not commmitted, so instantiating a new `crontab` object will read the existing stuff, not  the "pending" work.

```py
    # Let's delete all test jobs.
    crontab.remove_all(comment="test")
    # There should be no job at all now.
    self.assertEqual(crontab.__len__(), 0)
    # <- changes not saved here
    # Just to be sure, let's create a new crontab instance and verify this information.
    clean_crontab = CronTab(user="root") # <- reads existing stuff from system, only goes up to the previous write
```

Also

> ```
>  self.assertEqual(crontab.__len__(), 0)
> ```

WTF you're not supposed to call dunder methods directly unless you're overriding them.

Comment: (for the \_\_len\_\_, idk why I wrote it that way, you're absolutely right)

Comment: thanks a lot, because len(crontab) was equal to 0 after calling remove_all, I thought it was not necessary to call crontab.write()